# Android PhoneGap application error in camera API

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on the camera API in Android using PhoneGap.  This app works fine in Android 2.2 but crashes after capturing an image in on an Android tablet running 3.2. It's also not working in the emulator running 3.2 and shows errors like "Sorry. the application Camera (process com.andoid.camera) has stopped unexpectedly".